# Disable critic for an entire file - Parse::RecDescent precompiled parser & PerlCritic/Tidyall

Tags: perl, perl-critic, parse-recdescent

I'm trying to remove an error from my sanity-checking [when I push code to my git repo, there's a hook that checks the code with `perltidy` & `critic`... using `tidyall` as the handler.]

The specific issue I have is with a pre-compiled Grammar Parser.... and this is not something I want to dive in & fix (sorry - that's outside my comfort zone)

If I add a simple `## no critic` to the start of the file, then

```
perlcritic path/to/class/file.pm
```

comes back

```
path/to/class/file.pm source OK
```

however

```
tidyall --check-only -r .
```

comes back with

```
perlcritic /tmp/Code-TidyAll-Frb0/path/to/class/file.pm failed
    exited with 2 - output was:
Unrestricted '## no critic' annotation at line 6, column 1. (Miscellanea::ProhibitUnrestrictedNoCritic, severity 3)
```

I know I can fix this in the `tidyall.ini` file:

```
[PerlCritic lib]
select = **/*.{pm}
ignore = **/class/file.pm
```

.... however I feel there should be a *cleaner* solution.

(or, why doesn't `tidyall` critique the same as `critic`?)

Comment: Can you turn `## critic` back on at the end of the file? Also, is this pre-compile thing code you're using inside one of your code files, or is it something you've written in its own file? Or maybe a third-party dependency that just happens to live in your repository to make deployment easier?

Comment: @simbabque - this is a distinct & separate package, as created using `Parse::RecDescent->Precompile( { -standalone => 1, }, $grammar, 'My::Specific::Class' )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why doesn't `tidyall` critique the same as `critic`?

A simple `perlcritic` on the command line defaults to severity 5, unless you've configured something different in your `~/.perlcriticrc`. The rule `ProhibitUnrestrictedNoCritic` defaults to severity 3, so your `tidyall` is running `Perl::Critic` with at least severity 3. As per its documentation, you can change that via something like this in the `tidyall.ini`:

```
[PerlCritic]
argv = -severity 4
```

And then `tidyall`'s checks *should* be the same as a `perlcritic -4` from the command line. (Unless you've configured custom severity levels in your `.perlcriticrc`.)

---

*Update:* As per your comment, you want to check everything at the "brutal" level. In that case, you can create a `perlcriticrc` file containing the line `[-Miscellanea::ProhibitUnrestrictedNoCritic]` which will disable that policy, and then point `perlcritic` at that file by adding the command-line argument `--profile /path/to/custom/perlcriticrc`.

Comment: I'm actually running a `brutal` level, which makes the whole Package un-checkable... however you have answered one of the questions asked

Comment: yes I did.... I've been distracted by a broken service - however I'll also try that. This would give two options: (a) exclude the whole file, or (b) allow the 'no critic' options - which is nice